# CListBox like flat client edge for a custom drawn windows control

Tags: mfc, listbox

A MFC CListBox control has a client edge which is not sunken, but just a border.

I want my custom CWnd derived control to have such a border. How do I do it?

WS_EX_STATICEDGE gives a slightly sunken style, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE gives a deep inset border,
WS_BORDER gives a black border. So none of them match the CListBox  control border.

Answer (score 0):

In the property window of your CWnd (right click while in your CWnd --> properties) there should have styles and extended styles to match your request.

Comment: They don't give the same representation... try it!